# How to build Chromium from source on OpenBSD?

Tags: chrome

If I check ex.:

```
curl -s http://ftp5.eu.openbsd.org/ftp/pub/OpenBSD/5.3/packages/amd64/ |grep -i chromium
```

Then I can see that for the most up-to-date Chrome for the latest stable OpenBSD is: chromium-24.0.1312.6.

On the latest stable Fedora (19): chromium-27.0.1453.93-2.fc19.x86_64.rpm

How can I make a fresh Chromium from source? (since there aren't any methods to get a more up-to-date Chromium)

Comment: What are these chromium versions in this OpenBSD ports: http://ports.su/www/chromium & http://ports.su/www/chromium,proprietary

Comment: http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20130502195841

Comment: That's great news! But how do they do that automagically? How can we compile an up-to-date Chromium from source?

Comment: Read through the ports FAQ: http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html. Not trying to be vague, just not familiar with openbsd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out: ports.su get's it's fresh packages from ex.:

- ftp://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/packages/amd64/

Thanks slm!